# C#. Client-server application

Tags: c#, tcp

I make a small server app which uses TCP protocol. It is already able to establish connection between multiple clients. The problem is that it works locally. So I am wondering how can i get host's IP address and make the server accept client connections over the Internet?

```
public static class Server
{
    static Socket socket = new Socket(SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    static int nextID = 1;
    static List<Socket> clients = new List<Socket>(5);
    static MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(new byte[256], 0, 256, true, true);
    static BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(stream);
    static BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(stream);
    public static void Init()
    {
        Console.Title = "Server";
        socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 8080));
        socket.Listen(0);
        socket.BeginAccept(AcceptCallBack, null);
        
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void AcceptCallBack(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        Socket client = socket.EndAccept(ar);
        clients.Add(client);
        Thread thread = new Thread(HandleClient);
        thread.Start(client);
        socket.BeginAccept(AcceptCallBack, null);
    }

    static void HandleClient(object obj)
    {
        Socket client = (Socket)obj;
        while(true)
        {
            stream.Position = 0;
            client.Receive(stream.GetBuffer());

            int code = reader.ReadInt32();

            switch(code)
            {
                case 0:
                    writer.Write(nextID++);
                    socket.Send(stream.GetBuffer());
                    break;
                case 1:
                    foreach (Socket cl in clients)
                        if (cl != client)
                            cl.Send(stream.GetBuffer());
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As long as there is a route between two PCs TCP should work.  One of the following is preventing the connection 1) The clients are not configured properly 2) The port is being blocked 3) There is not route 4) Another connection is using the port number.

Comment: Seems legit. But is there any way to configure everything programmatically, for example, open ports so that the client won't have to configure anything?

Comment: You should allow app through firewall on each end. Then it should work as you test it. Try to setup VM to verify your solution between two machines

Comment: _"I am wondering how can i get host's IP address and make the server accept client connections over the Internet?"_ -- too broad. What have you _tried_? There are mechanisms to get your Internet-facing IP address, as well as to automatically configure port forwarding for a NAT router (e.g. UPnP), but we don't have any information on your actual network configuration, and even if we did, it's too broad a question to ask Stack Overflow to walk you through all the little details. You need to do some research and ask for help here if you have something _specific_ you need help with.

Comment: There is a the internet and local networks.  Most home networks there is one gateway IP address.  So any machine behind the gateway does not have an IP address where a TCP connection can be made to another machine on the internet.  To test if a machine can be reached first try from cmd.exe >Ping IP (or machine name).  If PING works than most likely the port is being blocked.  If PING doesn't work, a route doesn't exist between the two machines.  Which either means you are in a local network and will never get a connection, or there is a configuration issue.